# how to view custom provider's events(collected without provider registered) by wpa

Tags: etw, xperf, windows-performance-analyzer

I try to use manifested base event to log event for debugging and analyzing.
But I have a problem: when I record with my provider registered, everything is fine, when open .etl file in WPA, I can view as much info as I can.
But if I collect events without my provider registered, when I open .etl file in WPA, everything is not human friendly.
So, must I register my provider before I start collect events? I hope not, because if so, I have to take the risk to leak my .man file, so others may use it to get the detail trace log as well. that's not acceptable!

I don't want my .man file packaged in install file, so I do not need to worry about leak it. and of course I can't register my provider as well.

Is there a way to view the .etl (collect without my provider registed first) as well as possible?

thanks in advance.

below are pictures that may make what i said more easy to understand.

image of record without my provider registered:

[image: image:record without my provider registered]

image of record with my provider registered:

[image: image:record with my provider registered]

Comment: what happens if you install the manifest on a developer machine and open the ETL on the developer machine?

Comment: If I installed the manifest, I will get all the information i want. like the second picture. human-readable *event data,provider name, task name, everything!* that's what I want! I can see nothing useful on the first picture, right?

Comment: so why not record without manifest on users machine, then copy to your developer machine with a manifest present, and you can see the proper data?

Comment: @Sirotnikov I do, what essential extra step is ***xperf -merge***, without it, I got nothing good.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer at msdn forums, [here is the same question asked by myself.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/65662da5-e68c-4052-bdf0-44f569ddf3fd/how-to-view-custom-providers-eventscollected-without-provider-registered-by-wpa?forum=wptkv5)

## ***xperf -merge*** is the key!

whole steps as follow:

1. install my software and start collect event data on custom's machine. (no need to register my provider.)
   call `xperf -start mysession -on MY_PROVIDER_GUID` start collecting event data.
2. after run some time, call `xperf -stop mysession -d poor.etl` to stop collecting and save to ***poor.etl*** file.
3. copy ***poor.etl*** to my dev machine(my provider already registered) and call`xperf -merge poor.etl good.etl`
4. open ***good.etl*** with wpa, I can see every details as I expected.

that's all. hope it will help other guy like me. thanks everyone.

Comment: ok, yes, you always need to merge them. this also adds information to load symbols. this is written in all guides.

Answer (score 0):

Use [EventSource package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource) if you use .Net, which adds manifest into the ETL (`ProviderName/ManifestData`).

With this way, you don't need to have manifest installed on capture and decode system. The manifest is now part of the ETL.

Of course, If someone gets the ETL, he can use [Perfview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) to dump the Manifest.

Comment: thanks for your tip, I just start notice the **ProviderName/ManifestData** information on my second picture. (captured with my provider registered)
>Of course, If someone gets the ETL, he can use Perfview to dump the Manifest.

that not sound good. I don't want other know my secret so easy.

I am wondering what others use ETW for? logging(anyone like me)?

Comment: I hope Microsoft must have considered this condition(used for logging and security) and they must have designed something, haven't they?

by the way, I can manually parsing the .etl file(recorded without my provider registered), event data is all there(binary form). there is no sense, wpa can't read them, really puzzled.

Comment: EventSource is designed to have manifest included to avoid registering of manifests.